# android - google play services 7.3.0 causes crash

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was using google play services 6.5.87 until now but I wanted to use [Android place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker) in my app. This requires play services version 7.0.0 and above.

I changed google play services version to 7.3.0(latest, tried 7.0.0 as well), but this started causing crash on kit kat and below devices. Following are the errors that came up:

1. The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
2. NoClassDefFoundError
3. java.lang.VerfiyError

I tried googling for solution. Someone suggested changing jdk from 1.8 to 1.7(tried but didn't work). But when we change play services version from 7.x.x to 6.5.87 everything works just fine.

Somewhere I read that wear doesn't support 7.3.0 so that could be the reason. I tried specifying screen sizes, and that didn't help.

Any lead will be of immense help.

Comment: Is this question for Android Wear only or for Android as a whole?

Comment: As of now mobile, tablets, phablets only as I don't intend to support wear devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the root cause for it, in your build.gradle(app) file

1. inside defaultConfig, set multiDexEnabled flag to true ([MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html))
2. Put compile dependency `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` under dependencies

Now, in your Application class, add this

`@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }`

This works.